# unexpected Shapiro results python

Tags: python, statistics

Shapiro p value does not show normality though histogram and qqplot seem to show normality. My concern is if I am correctly using the scipy Shapiro function.

```
pty.hist(RankList[4])
sm.qqplot(np.array(RankList[4]), line='s')
print(stats.shapiro(RankList[4]))
pty.show()
```

RESULT From Shapiro

(0.9911481738090515, 7.637918031377922e-08)

I would expect the p value to be higher.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have quite a bit of data, if you check the notes on the [SciPy documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.shapiro.html) it states:

> For N > 5000 the W test statistic is accurate but the p-value may not be.

You may want to consider using the [Anderson Darling test.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson.html#scipy.stats.anderson)